# Discord.net create a role with a color using RGB or HEX (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, role, discord.net

I'm trying to make a role but it doesn't seem to let me change the color using RGB/HEX, only the ones it supplies

```
     Await message.Server.CreateRole(name:="Role", permissions:=Nothing, color:=color.default, isHoisted:=False, isMentionable:=False)
```

I know that it's because it can't use anything that isn't the type 'color' but is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you show the code where you attempt to provide your own colour?

Comment: Create a new `Color` object and pass in the RGB value for the parameters. Then pass that `Color` object to the color parameter in `message.Server.CreateRole`.

Comment: Perhaps [Color.FromRgb()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Sorry for not replying for a bit, but none of these were exactly what I was looking for, but thanks for your help anyway. I found out the class discord.color is actually already a HEX code, but I have no idea in how to put my own in it since the main error is something like string/ULong/Interger ETC. can't be converted to color. It makes sense but I don't know if there's a way to convert it to color or another solution.